# same object for same values in pands data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, class

I have a pandas dataframe : `df[Country, Date, Infection, Average]`.

And i have a class **Date** with year date and month as instance variable.

It is a requirement that for one and the same date, only one object (instance) must exist in the data structure.

IS this possible. And how can i do this?

Output:
There will be a column in data frame which will have the objects of Date class.

```
               Country          Date  Infection  Average Date_Object
0      Afghanistan,AFG  Dec 31, 2019        0.0    -89.0  Same
1      Afghanistan,AFG   Jan 1, 2020        0.0    -88.0
2      Afghanistan,AFG   Jan 2, 2020        0.0    -87.0
3      Afghanistan,AFG   Jan 3, 2020        0.0    -86.0
4      Afghanistan,AFG   Jan 4, 2020        0.0    -85.0
5      Afghanistan,AFG  Dec 31, 2019        0.0    -89.0  Same
```

Like here the date are same dec 31, 2019. so the objects should be also same.

Date Class:

```
import datetime
class Date:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%b %d, %Y")
        self.year = self.date.year
        self.month = self.date.month
        self.day = self.date.day
```

Comment: add an example and expected output

Comment: Edited with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each date, you can store the object in a dictionary using the date as a key.  When adding the objects to your pandas dataframe, you can simply write a function to create and store the Date object if it has not yet been created, or obtain an existing Date object from the dictionary, thus avoiding creating multiple objects per date.

Something like this:

```
dates = {}
def get_date_object(date):
     if date in dates:
          date_obj = dates[date]
     else:
          date_obj = Date(date)
          dates[date] = date_obj
     return date_obj
```

You can then modify the dataframe as such:

```
df.loc[:, 'Date_Object'] = [get_date_object(date) for date in df.loc[:, 'Date']]
```